# Múltiples comprobaciones de datos en python

Tags: python

Les comento, estuve experimentando con un intento de programa. Pero en un punto hace falta hacer múltiples verificaciones de datos, La verdad que creo es una tontería pero así y todo no pude lograr hacerlo xD. La idea es que al final verifique que si los aminoácidos(Triptofano, Treonina, etc) son mayores a los establecidos en el diccionario "prote_completa" y si es así, suma una proteina al contador Total_ProteC y resta los aminoácidos a las variables  de los mismos.

```
prote_completa = {
    "Triptófano": 7.7,
    "Treonina": 27,
    "Isoleucina": 25,
    "Leucina": 55,
    "Lisina": 51,
    "Metionina": 25,       
    "Cistina": 25,
    "Fenilalanina": 47,
    "Tirosina": 47,
    "Valina": 32,
    "Histidina": 18
}

Lenteja = {
    "Triptófano":0.81,
    "Treonina":3.23,
    "Isoleucina":3.9,
    "Leucina":6.54,            
    "Lisina":6.3,
    "Metionina":0.77,
    "Cistina":1.18,
    "Fenilalanina":4.45,
    "Tirosina":2.41,
    "Valina":4.48,
    "Histidina":2.54
}


elejir_gramos = float(input("Escoja los gramos: "))

Triptófano   = Lenteja["Triptófano"] * elejir_gramos
Treonina     = Lenteja["Treonina"]   * elejir_gramos
Isoleucina   = Lenteja["Isoleucina"] * elejir_gramos
Leucina      = Lenteja["Leucina"]    * elejir_gramos
Lisina       = Lenteja["Lisina"]     * elejir_gramos
Metionina    = Lenteja["Metionina"]  * elejir_gramos
Cistina      = Lenteja["Cistina"]    * elejir_gramos
Fenilalanina = Lenteja["Fenilalanina"] * elejir_gramos
Tirosina     = Lenteja["Tirosina"] * elejir_gramos
Valina       = Lenteja["Valina"] * elejir_gramos
Histidina    = Lenteja["Histidina"] * elejir_gramos


Total_ProteC = 0
while Triptófano >= prote_completa["Triptófano"]:
    continue                                     
    if Treonina >= prote_completa["Treonina"]:
        continue
        if Isoleucina >= prote_completa["Isoleucina"]:
            continue     
            if Leucina >= prote_completa["Leucina"]:
                continue 
                if Lisina >= prote_completa["Lisina"]:
                    continue
                    if Metionina >= prote_completa["Metionina"]:
                        continue
                        if Cistina >= prote_completa["Cistina"]:
                            continue         
                            if Fenilalanina >= prote_completa["Fenilalanina"]:
                                continue        
                                if Tirosina >= prote_completa["Tirosina"]:
                                    continue        
                                    if Valina >= prote_completa["Valina"]:
                                        continue        
                                        if Histidina >= prote_completa["Histidina"]:
                                            Total_ProteC += 1
                                            Triptófano -= 7.7
                                            Treonina -= 27 
                                            Isoleucina -= 25
                                            Leucina -= 55
                                            Lisina -= 52
                                            Metionina -= 25
                                            Cistina -= 25
                                            Fenilalanina -= 47
                                            Tirosina -= 47
                                            Valina -= 32
                                            Histidina -= 18
```

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperas, o qué error te da?

Comment: La idea es que devuelva la cantidad de proteinas completas, 1 prote completa se determina con la cantidad de aminoácidos que esta en el primer dict. Aunque al final del codigo me falto el print para mostrarlo

Comment: Entonces, ¿Lo que esperas es que si un aminoácido, por ejemplo **Triptófano** es mayor al valor que tiene en el diccionario **prote_completa**, sume 1 unidad al contador **Total_proteC**?

Comment: El mismo concepto pero con todos los aminoacidos, es decir, en el dict prote_completa están los valores que conforman 1g de proteina. entonces si en las variables de aminoacidos(Triptofano, Treonina,etc) son igual o mayores a las estableciadas en prote_completa. que sume 1 unidad al contador Total_ProteC y reste los aminoacidos para asi lograr la suma, de lo contrario si no se restan, no tendria con cenrteza cuantos gramos de proteína hay

Comment: Pregunta: ¿El aminoácido que decide si es una proteína es el calculado de menor cantidad, según la proporción del "alimento" (lenteja en este caso) comparado con la referencia prote_completa?. O sea, suponiendo que se calculan 25 unidades de Metionina pero hay 1000 de Leucina y de todas las otras, ¿igual sigue siendo una proteína?

Answer (score 0):

Después de analizar tu pregunta creo que lo que buscas es saber cuantas proteínas completas se forman. Si no estoy equivocado, para que se forme una proteína completa **tiene** que haber al menos la cantidad indicada en `prote_completa` de cada aminoacido. Entonces, si hay algún aminoácido que sea menor a la cantidad indicada en `prote_completa` no se podrá completar la proteína. Te dejo el siguiente código, ya lo probé y funciona a la perfección.

```
prote_completa = {
    "Triptófano": 7.7,
    "Treonina": 27,
    "Isoleucina": 25,
    "Leucina": 55,
    "Lisina": 51,
    "Metionina": 25,       
    "Cistina": 25,
    "Fenilalanina": 47,
    "Tirosina": 47,
    "Valina": 32,
    "Histidina": 18
}

Lenteja = {
    "Triptófano":0.81,
    "Treonina":3.23,
    "Isoleucina":3.9,
    "Leucina":6.54,            
    "Lisina":6.3,
    "Metionina":0.77,
    "Cistina":1.18,
    "Fenilalanina":4.45,
    "Tirosina":2.41,
    "Valina":4.48,
    "Histidina":2.54
}


elejir_gramos = float(input("\nEscoja los gramos: "))
print('\n\n')

newLenteja = dict()
for aminoacido in Lenteja:
    valor = Lenteja[aminoacido]*elejir_gramos
    newLenteja[aminoacido] = valor

Total_ProteC = 0
op = True
while op == True:
    for aminoacido in newLenteja:
        origin = prote_completa[aminoacido]
        new_val = newLenteja[aminoacido]
        if new_val >= origin:
            newLenteja[aminoacido] = new_val-origin
        else:
            op = False
            print(aminoacido)
    if op == True:
        Total_ProteC = Total_ProteC + 1


print("\n\nProteinas Completas: ", Total_ProteC, "\n\n")
```

Se puede hacer incluso mas compacto, pero creo que así lo puedes entender completamente. A continuación te explico el funcionamiento de cada parte:

### Input

```
elejir_gramos = float(input("\nEscoja los gramos: "))
```

Ingresas el numero de gramos

### Primer Bucle

```
newLenteja = dict()
for aminoacido in Lenteja:
    valor = Lenteja[aminoacido]*elejir_gramos
    newLenteja[aminoacido] = valor
```

`newLenteja` es un diccionario donde se almacenan los valores de cada aminoácido multiplicado por el numero de gramos. Por ejemplo si tu ingresas en el `input` el numero 100 obtendrías el valor de cada elemento de `Lenteja` multiplicado por 100. Todos estos valores se almacenan en `NewLenteja` con su respectiva clave (nombre del aminoácido).

### Segundo bucle

```
Total_ProteC = 0
op = True
while op == True:
    for aminoacido in newLenteja:
        origin = prote_completa[aminoacido]
        new_val = newLenteja[aminoacido]
        if new_val >= origin:
            newLenteja[aminoacido] = new_val-origin
        else:
            op = False
            print(aminoacido)
    if op == True:
        Total_ProteC = Total_ProteC + 1
```

Básicamente lo que hace este bucle es verificar que la cantidad de todos los aminoácidos cumplan con la condición de ser mayor a la cantidad establecida en `prote_completa`. Si es así, resta lo equivalente a 1 proteína y hace el mismo procedimiento hasta que un aminoácido no cumpla con la condición. Finalmente imprime la cantidad de proteínas completas.

### Test

Si por ejemplo ingresas 100 en el `input`, la cantidad de proteínas completas seria de **3**, ya que por ejemplo, en `Lenteja` tienes que:

```
"Metionina":0.77,
```

0.77x100 = 77, y una proteína completa necesita 25 de"Metionina", por lo que solo alcanza para 3. Espero haberte ayudado, creo que es eso lo que pretendías. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo, se tiene que cumplir con toda la proporción de aminoácidos de `prote_completa` para que sea una unidad de proteína.

Como las muestras (lentejas en este caso) tienen diferentes proporciones, entonces lo que define cuántas proteínas hay, es el que resulta menor en proporción.

Luego de tener la cantidad de proteinas (Total_ProteC), el sobrante sería `la cantidad de aminoácidos - (Total_ProteC * aminoacido_referencia)`

Llevando ese concepto a código, quedaría algo como:

```
gramos = float(input("Escoja los gramos: "))

proporciones = [] # Acumulará todas las proporciones de aminoácidos
for amin, value in Lenteja.items():
    amin_total = value * gramos
    proporciones.append(amin_total / prote_completa[amin])

Total_ProteC = int(min(proporciones)) # min retorna el valor menor de la lista
print()
print(f"Total de proteinas: {Total_ProteC}")
print("Aminoacidos restantes")
for amin, value in Lenteja.items():
    sobrante = (value * gramos) - (Total_ProteC * prote_completa[amin])
    print(f"{amin:15} -> {sobrante:.2f}")
```

Una salida de ejemplo:

```
Escoja los gramos: 110

Total de proteinas: 3
Aminoacidos restantes
Triptófano      -> 66.00
Treonina        -> 274.30
Isoleucina      -> 354.00
Leucina         -> 554.40
Lisina          -> 540.00
Metionina       -> 9.70
Cistina         -> 54.80
Fenilalanina    -> 348.50
Tirosina        -> 124.10
Valina          -> 396.80
Histidina       -> 225.40
```

Comment: Ahí comente como quedo finalmente, probé con este pero calculaba cada aminoácido por separado en vez de calcularlos a todos xd

Answer (score 0):

Después de leer las respuestas intente hacer funcionar el programa implementando sus pedazos de código para hacerlo mas eficiente, pero no pude lograrlo.
Si a alguien le interesa y le es de ayuda voy a explicar y poner el código como quedo finalmente.
Antes quiero decir que para que se forme una proteína completa, el alimento tiene que si o si cumplir con las validaciones que están basadas en el dict(prote_completa). si el alimento no cumple con eso, no se podrá formar el gramo de proteína. También es necesario restar la cantidad de aminoácidos en el dict(prote_completa) a las variables de estos, para que así el calculo sea preciso. Si alguien logra hacerlo mas optimo sea bienvenido, yo no pude xd. Finalmente quedo así:

```
prote_completa = {
    "Triptófano": 7,
    "Treonina": 27,
    "Isoleucina": 25,
    "Leucina": 55,
    "Lisina": 51,
    "Metionina": 25,       
    "Cistina": 25,
    "Fenilalanina": 47,
    "Tirosina": 47,
    "Valina": 32,
    "Histidina": 18
}

Lenteja = {   
    "Triptófano":0.81,
    "Treonina":3.23,
    "Isoleucina":3.9,
    "Leucina":6.54,             
    "Lisina":6.3,
    "Metionina":0.77,
    "Cistina":1.18,
    "Fenilalanina":4.45,
    "Tirosina":2.41,
    "Valina":4.48,
    "Histidina":2.54
}


Total_ProteC = 0

Triptófano_contador   = []
Treonina_contador     = []
Isoleucina_contador   = []
Leucina_contador      = []
Lisina_contador       = []
Metionina_contador    = []
Cistina_contador      = []
Fenilalanina_contador = [] 
Tirosina_contador     = []
Valina_contador       = []
Histidina_contador    = []


gramos_elejidos = float(input("Escoja los gramos: "))

Triptófano   = Lenteja["Triptófano"]   * gramos_elejidos
Treonina     = Lenteja["Treonina"]     * gramos_elejidos 
Isoleucina   = Lenteja["Isoleucina"]   * gramos_elejidos
Leucina      = Lenteja["Leucina"]      * gramos_elejidos
Lisina       = Lenteja["Lisina"]       * gramos_elejidos
Metionina    = Lenteja["Metionina"]    * gramos_elejidos
Cistina      = Lenteja["Cistina"]      * gramos_elejidos
Fenilalanina = Lenteja["Fenilalanina"] * gramos_elejidos
Tirosina     = Lenteja["Tirosina"]     * gramos_elejidos
Valina       = Lenteja["Valina"]       * gramos_elejidos
Histidina    = Lenteja["Histidina"]    * gramos_elejidos



while Triptófano >= prote_completa["Triptófano"] and Treonina >= prote_completa["Treonina"] and Isoleucina >= prote_completa["Isoleucina"] and Leucina >= prote_completa["Leucina"] and Lisina >= prote_completa["Lisina"] and Metionina >= prote_completa["Metionina"] and Cistina >= prote_completa["Cistina"] and Fenilalanina >= prote_completa["Fenilalanina"] and Tirosina >= prote_completa["Tirosina"] and Valina >= prote_completa["Valina"] and Histidina >= prote_completa["Histidina"]:

    Total_ProteC += 1
    Triptófano -= 7
    Treonina -= 27 
    Isoleucina -= 25
    Leucina -= 55
    Lisina -= 52
    Metionina -= 25
    Cistina -= 25
    Fenilalanina -= 47
    Tirosina -= 47
    Valina -= 32
    Histidina -= 18

print(Total_ProteC)
```

Comment: Quieres que se muestre cuanto falta para que el aminoácido sea una proteína o quieres obtener cuales aminoácidos no son proteínas. Esto más la cantidad de aminoácidos que so proteínas. ¿?

Comment: Para que una proteína se considera completa, hace falta que cumpla con un perfil de aminoácidos(prote_completa). Si esta no lo cumple, no se la considera completa.La idea del programa es que muestre la cantidad de proteínas completas en un alimento

Comment: Mi programa cumple eso (eso creo), podrías mostrar un resultado esperado?